# .Net remote debug web api with iOS app

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc

I built a Web API service that's hosted on Server in IIS. My company's project is mainly based on iOS App that runs on iPhone, it calls the web api method and retrieve JSON format data.

Here's the problem. I can't simulate data because there are codes which shows if you are not using iPhone then you get WrongParameter Exception, and the payment module must debug on the server because it's a tranfer from server 2 server.

So is there any ways that I can debug these methods by using iPhone with Visual Studio?

Comment: I know this doesn't help you now, but if you wrote the iOS app in C# using Xamarin then you could debug in Visual Studio.

Comment: So is there any other way to realize this debug?

Comment: By the way that was a good suggestion,I'll consider it when Xamarin is stable...

Comment: I don't think there is a way to debug an Objective-C app from Xcode in Visual Studio. You *could* use Fiddler to simulate Get/Post to the server.

Comment: Xamarin has been doing this for a few years. They're stable.

Comment: I use Xamarin for my mobile apps.

Comment: Yeah..Thx,I use Fidder,set my Iphone Internet proxy same 2 my PC and it worked.....